# Static Metamodel, jpa and field name as a string

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, metamodel

I generate metamodel of my entities with the Hibernate Static Metamodel Generator Annotation Processor. So, I can build criteria properly by using field (compilation check safe) like this instead of specifying directly the field name as a string :

```
MyClass_.myField
```

I migrate old code to this new system but some functions take string as argument and not SingularAttribute (metamodel type).

I don't want to change the signature of these functions for now.

My question : can I access to the field name using the metamodel and transform it to a string ?

I would like to do something like `MyClass_.myField.toString()` but it does not return the name of the field.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's so easy that I don't find it immediatly...

just call :

```
MyClass_.myField.getName()
```

Comment: This solution works only in the simplest case. It does not take into account the cases where you specfiy a different column name using the @Column annotation, for example.